# Faster algorithm for removing duplicates from dictionaries, compare of two

Tags: python, image, dictionary, duplicates, computer-vision

I'm currently working on notMINST database using python 2.7, trying to remove duplicated images.
I turn each image into MD5 hash, and created a dictionary image_hash

The first method works, however, it took almost an hour for there are altogether 500000 images in the dataset.

```
image_hash_identical = {}
for key,value in image_hash.items():
    if value not in image_hash_identical.values():
        image_hash_identical[key] = value
```

I tried to use 'set' function to create a second method to make things faster:

```
image_hash_set_values = list(set(image_hash.values()))
for i in range(len(image_hash_set_values)):
    for j in range(i, len(image_hash)):
        image_hash[j] == image_hash_set_values[i]:
            image_hash_identical[i] = image_hash[j]
            break
```

However, this code failed to accelerate the process for the 'set' function shuffled the order of image_hash. Are there any ways to inhibit the shuffling by 'set' function or any faster algorithms that can handle this situation?

Comment: Did you try building ```image_hash``` with the hash as the key?

Comment: No, not as a key, but as value. I used key to represent the ID of observasion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just keep track of seen values using a set:

```
image_hash_identical, seen = {}, set()
for key, value in image_hash.items():
    if value not in seen:  # contains of set: O(1)
        image_hash_identical[key] = value
        seen.add(value)
```

Comment: Keeping track of the seen values could be done while building ```image_hash```.

Comment: Very true, same principle. Especially given that you do not control the order of iteration, it is rather random which key stays in. But you don't always control the data you deal with...  :'(

Comment: Is this the same way of the first algorithm where `image_hash_identical.value()` works the same as `seen`?

Comment: @Xiuyuanc No. The call to `.values()` is much more costly because it returns a copy of the dict's values (`O(N)`) each loop iteration whereas the `set` `add` and `contains` are both `O(1)`.